# Convert CSV Rows to dictionary

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm working on analysing big data file which contains the review comments of users and I was asked to convert each rows to dictionary as key (word) and value (count of word in that row/review comment), to analyse usage of words.

Using below code, I was able to split the data but not able to convert the same to dictionary.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

products = pd.read_csv('product_comments.csv')
products['words_count'] = csv.DictReader(products['review'].str.lower().str.split())
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Show us your data, that you read from the csv file.

Comment: and edit your code properly please

Comment: `csv.DictReader` is for operating on a text file. Not a pandas data structure.

Comment: I have 2 column - name & review. name column has product name like 1) Planetwise Wipe Pouch,2) Annas Dream Full Quilt with 2 Shams, 3) Stop Pacifier Sucking without tears with Thumbuddy To Love\'s Binky Fairy Puppet and Adorable Book etc., 
in review column i have customers comments like - 1) it came early and was not disappointed. i love planet wise bags and now my wipe holder. it keps my osocozy wipes moist and does not leak. highly recommend it.
i need to add new column "products['words_count']" which is in dictionary type, key-word and value-count of word

Answer (score 0):

You could `apply` `Counter` to the `reviews` column to get a `dictionary` of word frequencies.

Random sample for illustration based on the `unix` word list:

```
word_file = "/usr/share/dict/words"
words = open(word_file).read().splitlines()[10:50]
random_word_list = [[' '.join(np.random.choice(words, size=100, replace=True))] for i in range(50)]

df.head()

                                             reviews
0  abaculus abacinate abalienate abaff abalone ab...
1  abalienation abacus abaction abacination abaca...
2  Ababdeh abalienate abaiser abaff abaca abactin...
3  abaction Aaru abandonee abalienate Aaronic aba...
4  abandon abampere abactor abactor abandon abacu...
```

Splitting on spaces and using `DataFrame.apply()` with the built-in `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
df.reviews.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: Counter(x))
```

You get:

```
0     {'Ababua': 5, 'abandon': 7, 'abaction': 3, 'ab...
1     {'Aaronical': 3, 'abandon': 1, 'abaction': 4, ...
2     {'Aaronical': 5, 'Ababua': 1, 'abaction': 1, '...
3     {'Aaronical': 3, 'abandon': 1, 'abaction': 7, ...
4     {'Aaronical': 4, 'abandon': 2, 'abaction': 2, ...
```